# Wordpress Conditional Javascript Include

Tags: javascript, wordpress, conditional-statements

I am trying to conditionally include javascript files on specific pages in wordpress. I finally found a snippet of code that does exactly what I want but it doesn't seem to be working. Any thoughts? I didn't include the real page names but I am using the page slug.

```
<?php if (is_page(array('page-slug','page-slug','page-slug'))) { ?>
   <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/script.js"></script>
<? } else { ?>
   <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/script.js"></script>
   <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/conditional-script.js">    </script>
<? } ?>
```

I Put this code where I call the rest of my scripts in my custom template files.

Comment: Although this doesn't solve your immediate problem, you should really be [enqueuing](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) your scripts as opposed to adding them to the header like you are doing. In regards to your question, can you expand upon what isn't working? Are all of the scripts loading on all pages? Are none of the scripts loading?

Comment: This code seems to break all calls to my scripts in my custom-footer.php which leads me to believe there is a syntax error in the code above. I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Do the scripts work correctly on their own, if not wrapped in a conditional statement?

Comment: Yes they work just fine if I remove these statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On third last line and last line, it looks like you are using `<?` to open the line. Try using `<?php` instead. So, it should be:

```
<?php
if (is_page(array('page-slug','page-slug','page-slug'))) 
{ ?>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/script.js"></script>
<?php
} 
else 
{ ?>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/conditional-script.js"></script>
<?php
}
?>
```

And as I mentioned, I would recommend [enqueuing scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) in the future ;)

Comment: UGhhh!! Such an easy fix, as are most. And thanks for the enqueuing tip! I'm actually already preventing the default WP jquery call and enqueuing jquery through google's CDN.

Comment: Haha, the easiest are often the easiest to overlook as well. Glad I was able to help!